# selectric not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectric

I would like to ask while the selectric dropdown is not working on  mobile simulator of google chrome. it uses the native version of the dropdown instead of the custom style one. Here's the image below:

**Selectric when on web desktop:**

[image]

**When on mobile:**

[image]

Comment: Which browser from which mobile device is the screenshot from?

Comment: This is the mobile simulator in chrome

Comment: OK, I can confirm this. I think this is by design – on mobile devices, you usually don't want to have these emulated dropdown menus but rather use the mobile device's native way of handling drop downs, because those are much more touch friendly.

Comment: Thanks Man, looks like that's how it really works.

Answer (score 4):

Please set the following options to try to enable selectric on mobile:

$el.selectric({
  disableOnMobile: false,
  nativeOnMobile: false
});
along with any other options you may be using.